# in Flutter how to get notified in specific time

Tags: flutter, time, notifications

I have an app for schedul event I want to get the time of the selected and event and allow the user to be notified at this specific time or before some time.
I have a data base with many events, the user choose the event so he can be notified before the start.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tArSx.jpg)

```
Text(
       DateTimeFormat.format(sh.premier,
       format: 'D, M j, H:i'),
       style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white,
       backgroundColor:
       Colors.black54),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

These can be done in two ways, you can use Flutter Local Notification, this can help you to schedule notification daily,at a specific time, weekly. Link to these and ref is:

[Plugin (Flutter local notifications)](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

[Medium article](https://medium.com/@nitishk72/flutter-local-notification-1e43a353877b)

Another preferred way is to use push notifications using Firebase this is by far mostly used to control notifications as it provides a custom control for particular users too!

[Medium article](https://medium.com/@SebastianEngel/easy-push-notifications-with-flutter-and-firebase-cloud-messaging-d96084f5954f)

[YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq9-DPKWtIc)